# How to access Json/Hstore elements in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, hstore

I have below data in my table

**STUDENT_INFO** TABLE

```
Column Data type
------------------
ID number
STUDENT_DATA hstore
```

Below is data

```
ID STUDENT_DATA
1        "config"=>"{"env": "TEST", "student": "10508"}", "payload"=>"{"Score_id": "201814", "Course": ["40359", "40360"]}"
```

From the above data I want to select Course

My Query is:

```
select ID,(hstore_to_json(STUDENT_DATA))->'payload'->>'course' 
from STUDENT_INFO 
limit 1
```

I am getting below error: -

> ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar

Can someone please help me write the query?

Comment: try `select ID,hstore_to_json(STUDENT_DATA)->'payload'->>'course' from STUDENT_INFO limit 1` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I am getting same error with above query as well

Comment: after you reveal your data I don't understand how its possible - `"config"=>"{"env"` does not look as hstore, which is key=>value, so after `"config"=>"{"` there needed comma and double quote and so on to format the value to be hstore...

Comment: You seem to be trying to store nested data in your HSTORE column. I'm not sure how you're even managing this: HSTORE is for key-value pairs, not nested data structures. I recommend using JSONB as your data type for `STUDENT_INFO.STUDENT_DATA`

Comment: Its already in our one of the tables.. I haven't created this structure. I am just trying to retrieve value for the reporting purpose. At this point I am trying to convert it into json 1st and then trying to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select ID,((hstore_to_json(STUDENT_DATA ))-> 'payload')::json#>'{Course}' from STUDENT_INFO LIMIT 1
```

I have tested below query and it does work

```
SELECT (select '{"Score_id" : 201814, "Course" : [40359, 40360]}'::json)::json#>'{Course}'
```

And you can also take ref from

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

you can consider below kind of example for that

```
SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>'{b,2}'

SELECT '{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]}'::json#>>'{a,2}'
```